# An argument working outside a function but fails inside a function in R

Tags: r, function, methods, eval, r-s4

When outside a function, argument `pbkrtest.limit = nobs(m1)` below works just fine (thus, no message is generated).

But when inside the `foo()` function, `nobs(m1)` is not recognized (thus, a message is generated)! I'm really wondering what is going on?

```
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/z.csv')

m1 <- lmer(y~ year*group + (1|stid), data = dat)

## WORKS FINE:
emtrends(m1, pairwise ~ group, var = "year", infer = c(T, T), pbkrtest.limit = nobs(m1)) 


## BUT NOW `nobs(m)` doesn't work inside the function:
foo <- function(m){

 emtrends(m, pairwise ~ group, var = "year", infer = c(T, T), pbkrtest.limit = nobs(m))
}

## RUN:
foo(m = m1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try evaluating it in the parent.frame:

```
foo <- function(m, envir = parent.frame()) {
  s <- substitute(emtrends(m, pairwise ~ group, var = "year", infer = c(TRUE, TRUE), 
    pbkrtest.limit = nobs(m)))
  eval(s, envir)
}

foo(m = m1)
```

and report it to the developer at https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues

Also use TRUE rather than T because T can be overridden but TRUE cannot be.

Comment: OK, but as the package developer, I don't get how I would be able to determine this parent.frame vis a vis the environment from which emtrends was called. I've never seen this issue before with an optional argument. There are lots of optional arguments for lots of methods for different models, and doing these kinds of gymnastics for each of them does not seem tenable.

Comment: Add an argument `envir = parent.frame()` to `emmeans` and modify the internals appropriately to use it. Then in situations like this the user can specify it.

Comment: Or, users could do what you do in your solution... There aren't a whole lot of R base functions that provide an optional `envir` argument; most are ones such as `eval()` where you'd expect it. I will evaluate how important and feasible this is to provide for.

Comment: Another possibility is to  use the environment of the formula and then it is up to the user to provide the correct environment when specifying the formula.  If fo is the formula then environment(fo) is its environment.

Comment: I still don't even have my head around why the second call doesn't work. The error is that it can't find `m`. But in the first case, it *can* find `m1`. In *both* cases, the name of the model is *in the environment from which `emtrends()` was called* -- right? I know the environments of the model formula are different relative to the calling environment, but the error comes from `nobs()` which doesn't use the model formula, would it? So why should it be any different?

Comment: The problem may be that your software is performing an eval without specifying the environment.  Normally the environment in the eval should be specified.  Try replacing eval(whatever) with eval(whatever, envir) and pass envir as an argument with a defualt of parent.frame().  You could try  hard coding parent.frame() and that might pick up some cases but would not be as flexible as passing envir.

Comment: Well, not *the* problem shown in the OP, since `nobs(m)` just got passed via `...` along with lazy evaluation. There were no existing `eval()` steps that would've changed it.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at this more closely in terms of the actual code in `emtrends()`. It boils down to what is demonstrated in the following code:

```r
# comparison of evaluation methods with lazy eval

# a trivial function
foo = function(x, ...)
    x^2


# calls foo three ways
foodoo = function(...) {
    message("x1 = ", foo(...))
    message("x2 = ", do.call("foo", list(...)))
    cl = match.call()
    cl[[1]] = quote(foo)
    message("x3 = ", eval(cl))
}

# test value
val = 3.5

# test runs
foodoo(x = 5)
## x1 = 25
## x2 = 25
## x3 = 25

foodoo(x = val)
## x1 = 12.25
## x2 = 12.25
## x3 = 12.25

# same tests, wrapped in a function...
bar = function(z) {
    foodoo(x = z)
}

bar(5)
## x1 = 25
## x2 = 25
## Error in foo(x = z): object 'z' not found

bar(val)
## x1 = 12.25
## x2 = 12.25
## Error in foo(x = z): object 'z' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The problem the OP experienced is related to that third method of evaluation. In `emtrends()`, the code matches the call, doctors it up for use by a different function, and then evaluates it. I'm not sure I fully understand all of this, but what is passed in function calls are actually promises, not values; a promose consists of an unevaluated expression and the environment in which it should be evaluated.

In looking at `foodoo()`, it appears that, with the first two methods, those promises are updated to the current environment before `foo` is called, whereas in the third method, the original call is kept intact so that the promises are not changed. And apparently (I'm still not quite sure why), those original environments are good enough when we call `foodoo()` from the global environment, but obviously not good enough when called from a different environment. If anybody cares to comment and explain further, I'm all ears.

Anyway, I am happy because I was able to fix the problem by forcing evaluation of all `...` arguments and replacing them in `cl`:

```r
# new foodoo
foodoo = function(...) {
    message("x1 = ", foo(...))
    message("x2 = ", do.call("foo", list(...)))
    cl = match.call()
    cl[[1]] = quote(foo)
    dots = eval(list(...))      # added
    cl[names(dots)] = dots      # added
    message("x3 = ", eval(cl))
}

bar(5)
## x1 = 25
## x2 = 25
## x3 = 25

bar(val)
## x1 = 12.25
## x2 = 12.25
## x3 = 12.25
```